# How can I collect multiple python program logs generated by standard output in Filebeat

Tags: logstash, filebeat, elk

I have several python programs are running as POD in Kubernetes Cluster on AWS EKS. I want Filebeat to automatically pick-up these logging events/messages from standard output to send it to ELK.

The current Filebeat configuration does not seem to work

```
data:
  filebeat.yml: |-
    filebeat.inputs:
    - type: container
      paths:
        - /var/log/containers/*.log
      processors:
        - add_kubernetes_metadata:
            host: ${NODE_NAME}
            matchers:
            - logs_path:
                logs_path: "/var/log/containers/"
```

How I can configure Filebeat or Logstash to collect standard out from several python program(s) and automatically ship it to ELK machine?

Answer (score 0):

The above configuration already generates combined logs from all the programs running on a container.

So, this is a correct configuration and one doesn't need to do anything else. It's just that I was not familiar with Kibana hence I could not find it earlier.

```
data:
  filebeat.yml: |-
    filebeat.inputs:
    - type: container
      paths:
        - /var/log/containers/*.log
      processors:
        - add_kubernetes_metadata:
            host: ${NODE_NAME}
            matchers:
            - logs_path:
                logs_path: "/var/log/containers/"
```

For Kibana, one needs to apply following wildcard filters to get the respective logs.

```
*<program_name>*
```

One can apply additional filter on top of that with `kubernetes.namespace:<namespace>`